# how to block An specfic URl from engintron(nginx)

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

Hello I need to block a specific URL form engintron (nginx)

```
app.worldindia.com/pubclick/click?affiate_id=683&appoffer_id=4523&trans_id=53e5232
app.worldindia.com/pubclick/click?affiate_id=683&appoffer_id=4523&trans_id=53dad24
app.worldindia.com/pubclick/click?affiate_id=683&appoffer_id=4523&trans_id=9dsdm44
app.worldindia.com/pubclick/click?affiate_id=683&appoffer_id=4523&trans_id=5j33231
app.worldindia.com/pubclick/click?affiate_id=683&appoffer_id=4523&trans_id=51fsd32
app.worldindia.com/pubclick/click?affiate_id=683&appoffer_id=4523&trans_id=9823d22
```

I need to block the url of specific affiliate with affiliate_id=683.  All the traffic coming from this affiliate  will go to status code 404

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below command if you want to block the particular url
iptables -A INPUT -d "app.worldindia.com" -p tcp -j DROP
```

Comment: I dont want to block "app.worldindia.com" link. I want it to be a specfic link "app.worldindia.com/pubclick/click?affiate_id=683&appoffer_id=4523"

Comment: for i in url1 url2 url3 …..;
do
iptables -A INPUT -d “$i” -p tcp -j DROP;
done

Comment: above command will work for you mention the url in for loop as i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

### Use nginx's [$arg_](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) variable[<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305851/nginx-location-regexp-for-query-string)

*nginx.conf*

```
⋮

location = /pubclick/click {
    if ( $arg_affiate_id = "683" ) {
        return 404;
    }
    # {OTHER CODE HERE IF NOT 683}
}

⋮
```

Comment: _P.S. There doesn't appear to be `else` in nginx.conf syntax—it isn't necessary in this case as we're `return`ing and the rest of location block won't be evaluated anyways._

Answer (score 0):

Really easy to do this in [Engintron](https://engintron.com/)'s custom rules:

```
if ($SITE ~* (app.worldindia.com/pubclick/click?affiate_id=683) {
    return 403;
}
```

This will match all the URLs with that affiliate ID. By the way it's better to use a 403 to deny access.